# JsonPath/Jackson: how to deserialize JSON array to a single Object ("[1,2,3]" -> Vector3d instance)?

Tags: java, jackson, jsonpath

**Abstract**

I'm using JsonPath to select parts of a JSON file and deserialize it into POJOs. This works fine for Strings, but I can't figure out how to get Jackson to deserialize a three-element array as a single instance of my own class (Vector3d). All the examples in the Jackson documentation seem to involve to element in JSON being converted to exactly one Java object. Any ideas?

**What the documentation says**

The [JsonPath documentation](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/blob/master/README.md) mentions that

> If you configure JsonPath to use the JacksonMappingProvider you can even map your JsonPath output directly into POJO's.
>
> Book book = JsonPath.parse(json).read("$.store.book[0]", Book.class);

But I can't get it to work.

**What I've tried**

My `Vector3d` class looks as follows (note the `@JsonCreator` constructor):

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;

public final class Vector3d {
    private final int x, y, z;

    public Vector3d(int x, int y, int z) { 
        this.x = x; this.y = y; this.z = z;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public Vector3d(int[] values) { 
        this(values[0], values[1], values[2]); 
    }
}
```

For this example (the actual file I work with is more complex):

```
{
    type: "viper",
    location: [
        20,
        173,
        153
    ]
}
```

I can get the 'location' vector as a three-element array as follows (this code is overly verbose, but just to keep the next step small):

```java
package main;

import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonReader;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.mapper.JacksonMappingProvider;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.mapper.MappingProvider;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration configuration = Configuration.defaultConfiguration();
        MappingProvider mappingProvider = new JacksonMappingProvider();
        configuration.mappingProvider(mappingProvider);
        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(configuration);
        DocumentContext documentContext = jsonReader.parse("{\n" +
                "\ttype: \"viper\",\n" +
                "\tlocation: [\n" +
                "\t\t20,\n" +
                "\t\t173,\n" +
                "\t\t153\n" +
                "\t]\n" +
                "}");
        int[] data = documentContext.read("$.location", int[].class);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    }
}
```

But if I use Vector3d instead of int[] in the last line, I get an exception during the read() call:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid or non Implemented status createArray() in class net.minidev.json.writer.BeansMapper$Bean
    at net.minidev.json.writer.JsonReaderI.createArray(JsonReaderI.java:98)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserBase.readArray(JSONParserBase.java:235)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserBase.readFirst(JSONParserBase.java:298)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserBase.parse(JSONParserBase.java:154)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserString.parse(JSONParserString.java:58)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:261)
    at net.minidev.json.JSONValue.parse(JSONValue.java:206)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.mapper.JsonSmartMappingProvider.map(JsonSmartMappingProvider.java:86)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonReader.convert(JsonReader.java:174)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonReader.read(JsonReader.java:140)
    at main.Tester.main(Tester.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I'm confused that the `Vector3d` construction doesn't work although deserialization to `int[]` works, and added `@JsonCreator` constructor that takes `int[]`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if there is an issue with inner non static classes. This works for me:

```
public class VectorTest {

    private static final String JSON = "{\n" +
            "    \"type\": \"viper\",\n" +
            "    \"location\": [\n" +
            "        20,\n" +
            "        173,\n" +
            "        153\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "}";

    static {
        Configuration.setDefaults(new Configuration.Defaults() {
            private final JsonProvider jsonProvider = new JacksonJsonProvider();
            private final MappingProvider mappingProvider = new JacksonMappingProvider();
            private final Set<Option> options = EnumSet.noneOf(Option.class);

            public JsonProvider jsonProvider() {
                return jsonProvider;
            }

            @Override
            public MappingProvider mappingProvider() {
                return mappingProvider;
            }

            @Override
            public Set<Option> options() {
                return options;
            }
        });
    }

    public static final class Vector3d {
        public final int x, y, z;

        @JsonCreator
        public Vector3d(int[] values) {
            this.x = values[0];
            this.y = values[1];
            this.z = values[2];
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void a_test() {
        Vector3d vector = JsonPath.parse(JSON).read("$.location", Vector3d.class);

        Assert.assertThat(vector.x, is(20));
        Assert.assertThat(vector.y, is(173));
        Assert.assertThat(vector.z, is(153));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach works, thanks! I think my problem was that I didn't use a `JacksonJsonProvider` (I didn't know that was necessary), plus my error ignoring the result from the call `configuration.mappingProvider(mappingProvider)`; I thought it was a setter, but it's a builder method.

All my classes were top level, so there was no problem with instance classes.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there were two problems. First, where I wrote

```java
configuration.mappingProvider(mappingProvider);
```

I should have written:

```java
configuration = configuration.mappingProvider(mappingProvider);
```

Second, I couldn't get the annotations to work, but I did manage with a custom Deserializer. Since I prefer my value classes not to be tied to a particular JSON serialization format, I defined it as a mixin:

```java
class JsonReaders {
    private JsonReaders() { } 

    static class MixinModule extends SimpleModule {
        static class Vector3dDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Vector3d> {
            @Override
            public Vector3d deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                int[] values = jp.readValueAs(int[].class);
                return new Vector3d(values[0], values[1], values[2]);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
            super.setupModule(context);
            SimpleDeserializers deserializers = new SimpleDeserializers();
            deserializers.addDeserializer(Vector3d.class, new Vector3dDeserializer());
            context.addDeserializers(deserializers);
        }
    }

    public static Configuration createConfiguration() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new MixinModule());
        MappingProvider mappingProvider = new JacksonMappingProvider(objectMapper);
        Configuration configuration = Configuration.defaultConfiguration()
                .mappingProvider(mappingProvider);
        return configuration;
    }

    public static JsonReader createReader() {
        JsonReader result = new JsonReader(createConfiguration());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Using a JsonReader defined as above, the code `jsonReader.read("$.location", Vector3d.class)` works. Unfortunately this way, it takes > 10x as long to parse a fix JSON file as before. If anyone knows a better solution, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To map your objects property "location" to the constructor variable use @JsonProperty:

```
@JsonCreator
public Vector3d(@JsonProperty("location") Integer[] values) {
    this(values[0], values[1], values[2]);
}
```

or name constructor variable same as in prop in json object('location')

```
@JsonCreator
public Vector3d(Integer[] location) {
    this(location[0], location[1], location[2]);
}
```

also I'm not sure is int[] is ok to serialize, so I used Integer[]

Comment: I specifically what to deserialize based on just the array, without the key name ("location"). Sorry, I just should have given a bigger JSON example to clarify: In my JSON files there are lots of different attributes that are all three-element arrays. I can select them all with JsonPath, and the I want to deserialize them into Vector3d objects. Effectively, Jackson only gets to see the fragment { [20, 173, 153] }, nothing else. Does it make sense to deserialize that with Jackson, or should I just deserialize to int[] and do the rest myself?