# JSONPath to transform and map to different tiers of data with a single output

Tags: json, xslt, xpath, transform, jsonpath

I am using [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) and this node module https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-object-transform to transform a JSON obj into a different output. This is similar to XML and XSLT. The problem is when I want to map to different tiers of the source data and send to a flat output.

Examples:

```
var output = {
    storeName: '$.store',
    items: ['$.items',{
        uniqueName: '$.name',
        sku: '$.skus[*].num'
    }]
};

var source = {
    store:'my store',
    items: [{
        name: 'Hammer',
        skus: [{
            num: '12345qwert'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Bike',
        skus: [{
            num: 'asdfghhj'
        }, {
            num: 'zxcvbn'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Fork',
        skus: [{
            num: '0987dfgh'
        }]
    }]
};
```

The result of this is:

```
{
  "storeName": "my store",
  "items": [
    {
      "uniqueName": "Hammer",
      "sku": "12345qwert"
    },
    {
      "uniqueName": "Bike",
      "sku": "asdfghhj"
    },
    {
      "uniqueName": "Fork",
      "sku": "0987dfgh"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem with the result is that it ignored the second array item in the `Bike` obj. `items[1].skus[1].num`. I believe it did this because `$.items` designator only knows of 3 obj in the items array.

My expected result was :

```
{
      "storeName": "my store",
      "items": [
        {
          "uniqueName": "Hammer",
          "sku": "12345qwert"
        },
        {
          "uniqueName": "Bike",
          "sku": "asdfghhj"
        },
{
          "uniqueName": "Bike",
          "sku": "zxcvbn"
        },
        {
          "uniqueName": "Fork",
          "sku": "0987dfgh"
        }
      ]
    }
```

How can I achieve this output using JSONPath.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JsonPath/Jackson: how to deserialize JSON array to a single Object ("\[1,2,3\]" -> Vector3d instance)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471589/jsonpath-jackson-how-to-deserialize-json-array-to-a-single-object-1-2-3)

Answer (score 2):

I tackled this kind of problem with my own small library which essentially mimics the XSLT processing model; so, here's a fiddle for your example:

https://jsfiddle.net/YSharpLanguage/2sa0twny

where:

```js
var source =
{
    store:'my store',
    items: [{
        name: 'Hammer',
        skus: [{
            num: '12345qwert'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Bike',
        skus: [{
            num: 'asdfghhj'
        }, {
            num: 'zxcvbn'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Fork',
        skus: [{
            num: '0987dfgh'
        }]
    }]
};

function Root(node) {
  return (typeof node.store === "string") &&
         ({ }.toString.call(node.items) === "[object Array]");
}

function SKU(node) {
  return typeof node.num === "string";
}

function FlattenedSKU(node) {
  return SKU(node) && (typeof node.name === "string");
}

var SO_30221930_Transform = { $: [

  [ [ Root ],
    // rewriting rule to process JSONPath's "$"
    // (XSLT-would-be <xsl:template match="/">...)
    function(root) {
      return {

        // (cf. the `String.prototype.of` interpolation helper)
        storeName: "{store}".of(root),

        // (XSLT-would-be <xsl:apply-templates select="items/sku"/>)
        items: root.items.
               // first, get all the SKU nodes (XPath "items//sku")
               nodeset(SKU, true).
               // then, flatten them as [ { name: ..., num: ... } ... ]
               map(function(sku_node) {
                 return {
                   name: "{name}".of(sku_node.parent.parent),
                   num: "{num}".of(sku_node.value),
                 };
               }).
               // finally, rewrite them as [ { uniqueName: ..., num: ... } ... ]
               through(this)
      }
    }
  ],

  [ [ FlattenedSKU ],
    function(sku) {
      return {
        uniqueName: "{name}".of(sku),
        num: "{num}".of(sku)
      };
    }
  ]

] };

var output = source.through(SO_30221930_Transform);
console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```

gives:

```js
{
  "storeName": "my store",
  "items": [
    {
      "uniqueName": "Hammer",
      "num": "12345qwert"
    },
    {
      "uniqueName": "Bike",
      "num": "asdfghhj"
    },
    {
      "uniqueName": "Bike",
      "num": "zxcvbn"
    },
    {
      "uniqueName": "Fork",
      "num": "0987dfgh"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here are other examples / use cases:

- [JSON transformations, revisited (XSLT look-alike)](https://jsfiddle.net/YSharpLanguage/kj9pk8oz/10)
- [Super-lightweight JSON-to-JSON transformations](https://jsfiddle.net/YSharpLanguage/ppfmmu15/10)

'Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

This may not be possible.  You are really iterating over skus, not items, so in theory the expression should be something like this:

```
var output = {
  storeName: '$.store',
  items: ['$.items[*].skus[*]', { // or '$..skus[*]', or perhaps even '$..num'
    uniqueName: '$<<name', // no "parent" operator in JSONPath
    sku: '$.num'
  }]
}
```

But there are two problems:

1) jsonpath-object-transform appears not to properly transform children: leaving out `uniquename`, if you omit the transform, the correct `num` entries are produced, but if you add a transform an exception is thrown.  I assume this is a bug.

2) even if you could iterate `skus`, JSONPath has no parent operator so there would be no way to access the current item `.name`.

Anyway, that's my best assessment.