# JSONPath to get multiple values from nested json

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have a nested JSON in a field that contains multiple important keys that I would like to retrieve as an array:

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": "task_1",
      "name": "task_1_name",
      "assignees": [
        {
          "id": "assignee_1",
          "name": "assignee_1_name"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "task_2",
      "name": "task_2_name",
      "assignees": [
        {
          "id": "assignee_2",
          "name": "assignee_2_name"
        },
        {
          "id": "assignee_3",
          "name": "assignee_3_name"
        }
      ]}]}
```

All the queries that I've tried so far fx `( $.tasks.*.assignees..id)` and many others have returned

```
[
  "assignee_1",
  "assignee_2",
  "assignee_3"
]
```

But what I need is:

```
[
  ["assignee_1"],
  ["assignee_2", "assignee_3"]
]
```

Is it possible to do with JSONPath or any script inside of it, without involving 3rd party tools?

Comment: The basic issue is that JSONPath is a *selection* language. It can select any of the items that are in your JSON, and it will give you a list of matches, such as `["assignee_1", "assignee_2", "assignee_3"]`. The result you want is not a selection, but a transformation - practically mapping "task" objects to arrays (`root.tasks.map(t => t.assignees.map(a => a.id))`. This is not something that JSONPath has been designed to do.

Comment: Similar question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221930/jsonpath-to-transform-and-map-to-different-tiers-of-data-with-a-single-output

Comment: That's a pity. Thank you for clarifying things @Tomalak !

Comment: What environment are you in?

Comment: I'm using Pentaho Data Integrator with Json Input step

Comment: I suppose you could [use a Javascript step](https://intellipaat.com/blog/tutorial/pentaho-tutorial/transforming-your-data-with-javascript-code-and-the-javascript-step/) instead - the code to get the data structure you want is in my first comment.

Comment: I may try to plug it into the stream indeed, I just hoped there's a solution to do it within the Json step using Json path. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're facing is that `tasks` and `assignees` are arrays.  You need to use `[*]` instead of `.*` to get the items in the array.  So your path should look like

```
$.tasks[*].assignees[*].id
```

You can try it at https://json-everything.net/json-path.

***NOTE** The output from my site will give you both the value and its location within the original document.*

### Edit

(I didn't read the whole thing :) )

You're not going to be able to get

```json
[
  ["assignee_1"],
  ["assignee_2", "assignee_3"]
]
```

because, as @Tomalak mentioned, JSON Path is a query language.  It's going to remove all structure and return only values.

Comment: As of 2023-10-24, https://json-everything.net/json-path is displaying a spinning 3d rendering for me.

Comment: That's the just the Blazor initialization screen.  Happy for you to open an issue at https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything with the browser, etc, that you're using.